# How to adding alphabet sequence to menu or choice

Tags: batch-file

I already know how to add an alphabet sequence to a menu (using ExitCodeAscii [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69731167/incrementing-alphabet-in-batch-file)), but this method makes the output slow.

Does anyone know a faster method with simple code?

I already tried this code: (just example)

```bash
:_Menu
@echo off
set "AZ1=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "AZ2=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
set "menu= one two three four five"
for %%A in (%AZ2%) do for %%M in (%menu%) do echo [%%A] %%M
set "_Choice=" &rem ????
rem choice /c !_Choice! /m "Choose...:"
rem if %Errorlevel%==""

pause
goto :_Menu
```

The output:

```
[A] one
[A] two
[A] three
[A] four
[A] five
[B] one
[B] two
[B] three
etc...
```

I want the output:

```
[A] one
[B] two
[C] three
[D] four
[E] five
```

Comment: Is this really the code you'd like us to assist you with? or have you just made something up for the purposes of a question? I have to ask because the code you submitted for [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78010450) output more results than there were letters in the alphabet. You will inevitably receive code which is difficult to modify to your specific needs, or that which is inefficient after doing so, if you don't clarify the exact task you are wanting to use it for. BTW, how is your second line `set "AZ1=...` relevant?

Comment: Haha. I want to know how to do it with several options and then choose the one that suits my needs. %AZ1% can be customizable like: set "AZ1= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"

Comment: You are not using the variable `AZ1`, as defined in your code. It should not therefore exist in a [mcve].

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm newbie. so the appropriate one might be %_Choice% not %AZ1%?

Comment: No, your subsequest code is not using a variable named `_Choice` either, so it should not be there. Currently, based upon your response to the existing answer, you have submitted code which works only with the type of content for the value of the variable named `AZ2`, even though your content is of the type for the value of the variable named `AZ1`. So your submitted code either doesn't work with the content, or the code does not attempt the task. In both cases your quesion fails to meet the required standard.

Comment: Check out [Dynamic Menu System](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67542833/1417694). We could expand on this as well by calling an additional FORMAT routine to make the menu look aligned no matter what the options are.

Comment: Your script nice and easy to use @Squashman . Based on ur script, I ask what variable of Errorlevel choice? I press any choice and get errorlevel value zero (0). I mean %retval% A usually output %errorlevel%=1, B=2, etc

Comment: Sorry @Compo . I not yet post next code that contains choice menu

Comment: `%retval%` is the variable you would use for any `IF` comparisons that you would need to decide what option to goto. The variable `%Option%` is the mapping to the actual Menu option name.  You can see that in this line of code: `echo You Selected: %retval% - %Option%`

Comment: I guess in theory, if your Menu options had values with NO spaces you could just use the `%Option%` variable with the goto. All the menu options would be labels to go to. Then all you would have to do is: `goto %Option%`. This way you don't need any `IF` comparisons.

Comment: Yes @Squashman, but i need  values of them:  %retval%, %Option%, %Errorlevel% for  more options. So i just select one i need . I already get Errorlevel value by adding this (set "num=%errorlevel%") at bottom choice /c !choices!... The output (You Selected: E - Boot Menu  - 5)

Comment: @Mr.Key7, we are not here to work on multiple questions and code outside of that which you've submitted in your question. It is very obvious that your task is considerably more involved that the simplified version you have submitted. The last few comments above are most certainly outside of the remit of the question. For this type of task, it is much better to submit all of your actual code, along with the entire task, including the actual and expected results.

Comment: @Mr.Key7, sorry but I am not understanding your last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute the inner `for` loop for each run of the outer loop. You don't want that.
Keep your original approach with the counter, but don't use the counter itself, but use it to extract a single char from the alphabet string:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "AZ1= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "menu= one two three four five"
set count=0
set "list= "
for %%M in (%menu%) do (
  set /a count+=1
  call set "list=!list!%%AZ1:~!count!,1%%"
  call echo [%%AZ1:~!count!,1%%]  %%M
  set "val[!count!]=%%M"
)
choice /c %list% /m "Choose:"
set "choice=!list:~%errorlevel%,1!"
echo/
echo you pressed [!list:~%errorlevel%,1!:%errorlevel%] !val[%errorlevel%]!
```

**EDIT** included additional request for saving the options for later use.

Comment: How to save output to variable? I tried set "List=!List! [%%AZ1:~!count!,1%%] %%M" but not same as output call echo...  then save only output ABCDE to variable.

Comment: see (slightly) expanded code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "AZ1=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "AZ2=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
set "menu= one two three four five"
for %%M in (%menu%) do SET "assign=y"&for %%A in (%AZ2%) do IF DEFINED assign IF NOT DEFINED option[%%A] SET option[%%A]=%%M&SET "assign="&ECHO [%%A] %%M
SET option

GOTO :EOF
```

It's normal practice to have a `setlocal` command directly after the initial `@echo off`. This discards any changes made to the environment when the batch ends, so variables established by one batch file do not affect any further batches that may be run in the same session.

If you run from a "shortcut", error messages will not be visible (they appear, but the batch continues & wipes them out). You *can* put a `pause` after statements & home in on the error, but better to [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) & run your batch from there so that the window remains open & any (error) messages will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

> Quick Boot Menu

Firmware Boot, OSLoader Boot, Reboot, Bios Setup, etc.

Finish editing and adapting script based on @squasman [Dynamic Menu System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67539331/what-am-i-doing-wrong-using-the-choice-command-with-batch/67542833#67542833).

Please check if there is something that is not correct, I will be happy to ask for correction

```
@echo off
goto:GetListMenu

:QuickBoot
cls
CALL :MENU %All_OS_Des% %_OtherBoot%
CALL :CHOSE
if /i %num% GTR !countwin! (call :OtherBoot) else (call :BootOS)
Goto:QuickBoot
:: #### END OF QuickBoot ####
rem Author: @Mr.Key7 : https://stackoverflow.com/users/23414967/mr-key7
rem Adapted from @squashman: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67539331/what-am-i-doing-wrong-using-the-choice-command-with-batch/67542833#67542833
================================================================================================

:GetListMenu
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FW_List="& set "WI_List="
set "countfw=0"
set "fwos=bcdedit /enum firmware ^| findstr "des" ^| findstr /v "PCI CD Setup Splash FDD Windows""
for /f "Tokens=2-4" %%B in ('%fwos%') do set /a "countfw+=1"& set "FW_List=!FW_List!"%%B %%C %%D" "
set "countwin=!countfw!"
set "wios=bcdedit /enum osloader ^| findstr "des" ^| find /v "Recovery""
for /f "Tokens=2-4" %%B in ('%wios%') do set /a "countwin+=1"& set "WI_List=!WI_List!"%%B %%C %%D" "
set "_OtherBoot="ReOpen" "ReBoot" "ShutDown" "SafeMode" "Bios Setup" "A. StarUp" "Exit""
rem echo [FWOS:!countfw!] [FWOS^+WINOS:!countwin!]
set "All_OS_Des=!FW_List!!WI_List!"
Goto:QuickBoot

:BootOS
for /f "tokens=1-2" %%D in ('echo %Option%') do set "F_DE=%%D %%E"
if /i %num% LEQ %countfw% (set "store=firmware") else (set "store=osloader")
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3" %%a in (`bcdedit /enum %store% ^| findstr "den des"`) DO (
    if /I "%%a"=="identifier" set "ID=%%b"
    if /I "%%b %%c"=="!F_DE!"   set "F_ID=!ID!"
)
if /I "!F_ID!"=="" (echo.& echo     FW/OS Not Found& timeout 2 >nul & exit /b)
if /I "!F_DE!"=="USB HDD:" call :USBCheck
rem echo.& echo     Boot to %Option%^?
rem echo    !F_ID!
rem set Opt=
rem set /p Opt=".   X=Cancel | Enter=Boot :"
rem if /I "%Opt%"=="x" exit /b
if /i %num% LEQ %countfw% ( bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} bootsequence !F_ID!
) else                    ( bcdedit /bootsequence !F_ID! )
shutdown /r /t 00 &exit

:OtherBoot
if /i "%Option%"=="Bios Setup"  shutdown /r /fw /t 00   &exit
if /i "%Option%"=="ReBoot"      shutdown /r /t 00       &exit
if /i "%Option%"=="A. StartUp"  shutdown /r /o /f /t 00 &exit
if /i "%Option%"=="ShutDown"    shutdown /s /t 00       &exit
if /i "%Option%"=="ReOpen"      start %~nx0             &exit
if /i "%Option%"=="SafeMode"    call :SafeMode
if /i "%Option%"=="Exit"                                &exit
exit /b

:SafeMode
wmic computersystem get BootupState | Find "Normal" >nul || call :ExitSafeB
bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal && call :BootS
    :ExitSafeB
bcdedit /enum {current} | Find "safeboot" >nul && bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
    :BootS
bcdedit /bootsequence {current}& shutdown /r /t 00& exit

:USBCheck
wmic diskdrive where InterfaceType='USB' get InterfaceType 2> nul | Find "USB" >nul || (
echo    insert an USB Drive first &timeout 3 >nul & goto :QuickBoot)

================================================================================================
REM Credit @squashman : https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman
:MENU
set /a "OptionNo=0"
set "choices="
FOR %%I IN (%*) do (
    set /a OptionNo+=1
    call :ResolveChar !OptionNo!
    set "Option!retval!=%%~I"
    set "choices=!choices!!retval!"
    echo [!retval!] %%~I
)
GOTO :EOF

:ResolveChar
SETLOCAL
  set "keys=_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
  set "_startchar=%1"
  CALL SET "char=%%keys:~%_startchar%,1%%"
ENDLOCAL & SET "retval=%char%"
goto :eof

:CHOSE
choice /c !choices! /m "Choose: " &rem /n
set "num=%errorlevel%"
call :ResolveChar %errorlevel%
set "Option=!Option%retval%!"
echo You Selected: [%retval%:%num%] - %Option%
GOTO :EOF
```

The Output on my PC:

```
[A] rEFInd Boot Manager
[B] MX23 (LinuX)
[C] Boot Menu
[D] USB HDD:
[E] ATA HDD: ADATA
[F] ThrottleStop UEFI
[G] \WIMBoot\DiskGenius-V5.5.0.1488
[H] \WIMBoot\EaseUS Partition Master
[I] \WIMBoot\EasyUEFI-v5.2-WinPE
[J] \WIMBoot\MiniTool.Partition.12.6.x64
[K] \WIMBoot\WinPE11x64-www.aioboot.com
[L] Windows 7 Ultimate
[M] \WimBoot\AOMEI_BackupperTP_v7.3
[N] DiskGenius - Boot
[O] Windows 10 Pro
[P] Windows 11 Pro
[Q] ReOpen
[R] ReBoot
[S] ShutDown
[T] SafeMode
[U] Bios Setup
[V] A. StarUp
[W] Exit
Choose: [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W]?
```

Comment: Spaghetti code. I would consider changing the flow of the script.  I really hate how you are using the goto to bounce around.

Comment: because I prefer the main menu (:QuickBoot) to be at the top. i just use goto when getting error with call